# How does AngularFire's valueChanges() method work here behind the scenes?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

**I'm developing an Angular application that connects to a Google Cloud Firestore database using AngularFire2. The application organizes content in projects. A user can participate in multiple projects, however he can only select and work on one project at a time** (I call it active project).

I wrote a service that wraps AngularFirestore to provide CRUD operations and also to hold the global state of the active project using a `BehaviorSubject`:

```js
class ProjectService {

  private activeProjectId = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  activeProject(): Observable<Project> {
    return this.activeProjectId.asObservable().pipe(
      switchMap(id => this.getOne(id))
    );
  }

  setActiveProject(id: string): void {
    this.activeProjectId.next(id);
  }

  getOne(id: string): Observable<Project> {
    return this.afs.collection('projects').doc<Project>(id).valueChanges();
  }

  // Some more CRUD methods here...

}
```

The active project state is updated from a higher order component that pulls the id of the active project from the `ActivatedRoute`:

```js
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.projectService.setActiveProject(params.id);
});
```

Lastly, I access the `ProjectService.activeProject()` a lot in my components but also in other services that need to know the currently selected project:

```js
this.projectService.activeProject.subscribe(project => /* ...do something with the data */);
```

**Now to my question: Does this approach make sense? Also I'm wondering what happens behind the scenes of AngularFire's `.valueChanges()` method here?** Does it create a new Firestore snapshot listener in the background for every Observable it returns? If this is the case, would it make sense to wrap the subscription in another `BehaviorSubject` to save reads and open connections:

```js
class ProjectService {

  private activeProjectId = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  private activeProject = new BehaviorSubject<Project>(null);

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.activeProjectId.asObservable()
      .pipe(switchMap(id => this.afs.collection('projects').doc(id).valueChanges()))
      .subscribe(project => this.activeProject.next(project));
  }

  activeProjectChanges(): Observable<Project> {
    return this.activeProject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

As I'm fairly new to reactive programming and Firestore any feedback is appreciated :-)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, this is important to determine what can make sense.about what does [valueChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/b2d44a8536de1e8a38152e8c60fef250af2e21a9/docs/version-5-upgrade.md) does background what exactly you are willing to detemine?

Comment: I think you should be subscribing to the behavior subject directly, no need to call activeProject(). I'd make behavior subject of type <Project> and switchMap on it directly in constructor() { this.activeProjectId.pipe(switchMap...) }. this way all new subscribers to subject will get last emitted value unless .next() is called at which point the switchMap will cancel previous subscription to firebase doc and start a new one

Comment: @ihorbond Could you maybe provide a quick example? I‘m not sure if I get it right.

Comment: @inhorbond I think your comment can be the answer, If you publish it as answer Iĺl be happy to upvote it